# Explaining the output of a C program using global variables

Tags: c, global-variables

```
void f(void);
int x = 15213;  
int main()  
{
    f();  
    printf("x = %d\n", x); 
    return 0; 
}

/* bar3.c */ 
int x; 
void f()
{ 
    x = 15212;
}
```

In the above code the output which i am getting is 15212. I dont understand how?

First the main function calls f() define in another c file. In f() the value of x is changed to 15212 from 15213. And then we are printing x. But the change that has been made to x should remain in f only right? X should have its scope limited to f() only . Even then it is printing 15212

Comment: `x` is a global variable.  Why would its scope be limited to `f`?

Comment: To get the behavior you seem to want, use `static int x` in both files.

Comment: `x` is declared outside of any function, so it's a global variable.  If you wan't `x`'s scope to be limited to `f()`, you have to declare it inside `f()` (and maybe make it `static`).  If you want its scope to be limited to one source file (such as `bar3.c`), definitely make it `static`.

Comment: @jwodder yes x is global then why isnt it picking the value 15213 which is defined in the main file. Instead it is using the value of x as defined in another file.

Comment: You've declared `x` at *file scope* (outside the body of any function) without the `static` keyword in both files, so both declarations are mapped to the same object in memory.  So when `f()` sets the value of `x`, that's the value `main` sees.

Comment: Because you need a good C beginners book where such a basics like variables scopes are explained

Answer (score 5):

You've defined the variable `x` with *external* linkage in 2 translation units. The behaviour of the program is therefore **undefined**. [C11 6.9p5](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9p5):

> 5. An external definition is an external declaration that is also a definition of a function (other than an inline definition) or an object. If an identifier declared with external linkage is used in an expression (other than as part of the operand of a sizeof or _Alignof operator whose result is an integer constant), somewhere in the entire program there **shall be exactly one external definition** for the identifier; otherwise, there shall be no more than one.

There is a common extension ([C11 J.5.11](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.5.11)), that is present on **POSIX** systems (Unix, Mac OSX, Linux) that cause such external variable definitions to be **merged** into one:

> J.5.11 Multiple external definitions
>
> 1. There may be more than one external definition for the identifier of an object, with or without the explicit use of the keyword extern; if the definitions disagree, or more than one is initialized, the behavior is undefined (6.9.2).

However C compilers for other platforms need not necessarily follow this rule.

---

If you want both files to have separate variables named `x`, prefix each declaration with the keyword `static`, i.e. `static int x;`. If you want them to be portably one, use `int x;` **only in one file**, and `extern int x;` in all others; this `extern`al declaration can be put into a header file.

Answer (score 1):

Because `x` is defined outside the scope of any function, it therefore has global scope.  So the running of `f()` to assign its value actually changes its value as shown.

When `main()` runs the first thing it does is call `f()` which changes the value (some may argue as a side effect).  That's why, the initialized value of 15213 is never used.